# SetInterval и ajax запрос jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, mysql

Данный скрипт подгружает новые комментарии из базы данных,
`setInterval('getcomment()',3000);` работает корректно, но! Проблема в том что он печатает
повторно в комментарии все выбранные комментарии (дублирует). То есть пример таков

1. коммент
2. коммент
3. коммент

через три секунды вызывается функция `getcomment` и печатается следующее

1. коммент 1
2. коммент 2
3. коммент 3
4. коммент 1
5. коммент 2
6. коммент 3

Очень хотелось бы что бы он не дублировал записи, и подгружал только новые добавленные комментарии. Подскажите как можно это пофиксить?

```
function getcomment(){
var id = $("#id").text();

$.ajax({
    url: "hook/comments.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {"id":id},
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data){

        $.each(data, function(one, data){

            $("#comments").append("<div id='comment'><h4>" + data.text + "</h4></div>");

            });

        }

    });

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    getcomment();
    setInterval('getcomment()',3000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете `.append()` конечно будут дублироваться.

Как один из вариантов очистите тег `$("#comments").html("");`
перед тем как вставлять данные

Comment: В общем то получилось неплохо, а какие ещё варианты возможны?

Comment: еще можно проверять существующие комментарии и в comment.php получать только новые, но я считаю это извращение и лишняя работа

Answer (score 0):

Делал подобную вещь, как было у меня:
страница через 10 сек кидает запрос на ajax.php который возвращает и старые и новые комменты, при этом выборка из БД была ORDER BY `microtime`, чтобы первыми выбирались старые записи, а уже потом старые.
И делал так: был <div id="comments"></div>, в который js изначально включал комменты, а уже потом он повторял тоже самое, но добавлял новые записи, через $("#comments").html(value).
Ничего не дергалось, работало нормально.
Но не думаю что это вариант при больших объемах данных.

Comment: вот в том то и дело что при больших объёмах данных это будет заметно как огромный кусок с комментариями сначала отчищается а потом заполняется

Comment: Кто сказал очищается? У меня лично ничего не очищалось, ровно подгружалось. Или можно еще круче: чтобы проверка была на новые комменты, это и спасет вас от повторений.

Comment: @dll, вам придётся очень сильно напрячь зрение, чтоб хоть чуть-чуть это заметить ;) Хотя, если комментариев будет больше, чем всё собрание "Война и мир", то краем глаза, всё же усечёте ;)

Comment: Помнится мне пример с автоматической подгрузкой контента по событию скролл, вот там подобная проблема решалась иначе, я попробую ещё сделать так же. А по поводу этого предложенного варианта, выделяешь текст, и после 3-х секунд он сбрасывается (выделенный). А если меньше секунд в setInterval поставить интервал? То вообще отличная защита от копирайтинга xD